# How to generate BlToolkit model

Tags: linq, orm

From what I have seen on the ormbattle.net, BlToolkit is the fastest ORM for .NET. I would like to test it in one of my projects, but I don't know how to generate entity classes. Should I do this by hand? I have 20+ tables in the database.

Is there any online tutorial or blog, where I can find more information about BlToolkit?
It looks like a library with great potential without community behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the following options:

1. T4 templates are available for some databases - http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc.T4Templates.ashx
2. MyGeneration and [template](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Template/?id=a1e54825-1926-43aa-8b1f-1addbab63b30) for BLToolkit.
3. Classes generated for Linq 2 SQL. BLToolkit can use L2S metadata.

Answer (score 6):

you can use our project on bltoolkit code generation:

http://sogen.codeplex.com/